# Missing google-play-services_lib under <sdk>/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm trying to set up Play Services for development. And I think I have installed all the necessary packages:
[image]

But at my `<sdk>/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/` there's nothing named as `google-play-services-lib`

```
   ~/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject$ ls -Ra.:
   .  ..  maps.jar
```

(There's simple no such directory as `google-play-services_lib` as indicated by the guide http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html...
So am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall, check permissions on the fs and then try to re-install it?

Comment: @HenriqueSousa what am I supposed to check against? I have a working SDK with which I can compile for targets without Google addon supports (say, Play). I'm confident that I'm the owner of the file directory and I just cannot find a folder that is supposed to exists (I'm sure that I have rw permission, yes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up getting a copy from others, putting it under the path. And now it works fine. (Still, just a workaround.

Comment: can u upload the folder that u put under your the path.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find them in /extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms, if you also updated Google Repository through the SDK Manager.

The individual libraries are in aar format, so you'll have to extract the jar yourself, if that's what you're after.